# How validate uniqueness and allow_blank with scope in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

User has a name, email and city.

Any 2 can be duplicated, but not all 3:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope:[ :email, :city ]
```

This works fine. How to add the following constraints?

email uniqueness `case_sensitive: false`.
city uniqueness `allow_blank: true`. Multiple users with same email and name are valid if city is blank.

Rails 4.2.5

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope:[ :email, :city ] if: Proc.new { |tbl| !tbl.city.blank? }
```

Comment: What about case_sensitive?